# Unable to delete Git branches using script

Tags: git, git-bash

I have few branches to delete and to accomplish this, i am trying to run a shell script on Git Bash (Win Server 2016). The script reads a text tile that contains list of branches. Here's the script:

```
$ cat clean_up.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
branch_list="$2"
git checkout master

while read -r branch
do
    git push origin -d $branch
    git branch -D $branch
done < "$branch_list"


$ cat branch_list.txt
service-integration
display
...
...

$ clean_up.sh repo_name /e/git/branch_list.txt
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
fatal: Invalid refspec ':service-integration?'
error: branch 'service-integration?' not found.
fatal: Invalid refspec ':display?'
error: branch 'display?' not found.
...
...

$ git --version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1
```

But if i manually `cd` into the repo and do a *git checkout branch_name*, and then try running the above commands to delete any branch (remote and local), it works just fine. I'm totally confused why it's not working from the script. :(

Comment: I'm not a Bash person, but I could recommend that you try creating a debug version of the script which, instead of running the actual commands, just echoes the string version of those commands to the console.  Have a closer look at what the script is actually doing (which probably is not what you think).

Comment: Does your text file have Windows or Unix line endings?

Comment: I tried echoing the commands and then tried running those manually on the command line. Since the branches are not locally checked-out, only the remote deletion command worked successfully (which is expected). I commented out the `local` branch deletion command and ran the script again. I still get this error for all branch entries: `fatal: Invalid refspec ':service-integration?'`

Comment: @LightBender: I am using Visual Code. Unlike Notepad++, i can't see any setting for enabling special chars but at the bottom right bar of the file, i see CRLF mentioned.

Comment: If it's a CRLF, the CR at the end of the line might be interpreted as part of the branch name.

Comment: Thanks a ton @LightBender! Changing it from CRLF to LF did the trick. :) Now please post this as an answer because i am eagerly waiting to accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have the line endings set to CRLF in the file you're importing. When you read in the file in a shell script, it's going to read the CR as a character at the end of the lien and interpret that as part of the branch name.

Comment: Thanks again! This was killing me since yesterday.